# How do I set a time limit to my splash screen?

Tags: android, eclipse, splash-screen

I am coding in Eclipse for an Android App. I have developed a splash screen which I need to display for 5 seconds before my app starts. How to do it?

Comment: use sleep method of thread

Answer (score 6):

```
       Thread timer=new Thread()
        {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent i=new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the Async Class to perform the sleep operation in the doinbackground function and in the post function do the rest of the task

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
        private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 5000;
        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
            {        super.onCreate(icicle);

            try{            
                this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             new MyAsyncTask().execute();   
            }

         private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
              @Override
              protected void onPreExecute(){
                    // show your progress dialog
              }
              @Override
              protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids){

                  try {
                        Thread.sleep(SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                return null;
              }

              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(Void params)
              {


                   startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));

                    finish();
              }

           }



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use like that

```
public class SplaceScreenActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME = 2500;

    // SplashScreen Splash;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splacescreen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(SplaceScreenActivity.this,
                        HomeScreenActivity.class);

                SplaceScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                SplaceScreenActivity.this.finish();

            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask or thread for this purpose.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you can use Sleep method like this in your Splash Activity onCreate method:

```
        Thread timer1 = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(4000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        }
    };
    timer1.start();
```

this take 4 sec to load NextActivity.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Handler handler = new Handler();

        Runnable run = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(SplaceActivity.this, New.class));
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                finish();
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(run, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `Timer`:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent home_page = new Intent(Splash.class,HomePage.class);
            startActivity(home_page);
            finish();
        }}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 2000;
        /** create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
        Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {
            int wait = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    super.run();
                    /**
                     * use while to get the splash time. Use sleep() to increase
                     * the wait variable for every 100L.
                     */
                    while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                        sleep(100);
                        wait += 100;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                } finally {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            HomeActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        welcomeThread.start();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these few lines of code in your splashActivity and it will start your second activity after 5seconds.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(splashScreen.this,MainActivity.class)
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    splashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

                    splashScreen.this.finish();
                }
            }, 5000);
```

> **PostDelayed** Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue, to
>   be run after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will
>   be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

Answer (score 0):

Use handler

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

int secondsDelayed = 5;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);


    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = 0;
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}


Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
 public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

        switch(msg.what)
        {
        case 1:
        {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
        }
        break;
        case 0:
        {
            Message ms = new Message();
            ms.what = 1;
            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(ms,  secondsDelayed * 1000);
        }
        break;
        }

    };
};



protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    mHandler.removeMessages(1);
};
}
```

**Note**:`Donot make Splash screen for 5 sec user will get irritated make it for 2sec`