# Full Screen Activity design and auto start new activity

Tags: java, android

In my application I have created a splash screen type of thing in android. It should remain for 5 seconds. My problem is that how I display another activity automatically after 5 secs? The splash screen doesn't have a button, rather it should display another activity automatically after 5 seconds without the click of the button.And please guide me how to design a new full screen activity. i got this code from stack overflow but as i am a beginner i dont know where to add this code can anyone please tell me.

Comment: Better to search on Google `How to deal with Splash Screen in Android ?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a time limit to my splash screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491073/how-do-i-set-a-time-limit-to-my-splash-screen)

Answer (score 1):

So lets say you have created a layout for your splash screen.
Then you will need to create an Activity for your splash screen.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash); //The layout for this activity

    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

            try {

                sleep(5000); //After 5 seconds your next activity will be displayed

            } catch(InterruptedException e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext, MainActivity.class); // The next activity you want to start
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };

    timerThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    finish();
}}
```

Then remeber to edit your activity category in your AndroidManifest.xml file, the splash screens category should be .LAUNCHER while your main activity should be .DEFAULT

```
        <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find on this tutorial how to create splash screen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwOuTjUFexE

Answer (score 0):

After the splash screen loads add the below code in on create

```
   try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);// You can change this depending on the requirement
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Your second activity will be loaded after 5 seconds automatically.

To make an activity full screen add the below line before setContentView :

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
}
```